# Preloader not working Properly

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, preloader

I am making a preloader in a **swf** like this

```
stop();
onEnterFrame = function ()
{
  loadPercent = Math.round(_root.getBytesLoaded() / _root.getBytesTotal()) * 100;
  loadBar._xscale = loadPercent;
  loadText.text = loadPercent + "%";
  if (loadPercent == 100)
  {
     play();
  }
};
```

and i am testing the movie with **Simulate Download** option to check if it is working.When i test it  flash player does not show the preloader . it only shows it for a fraction of second when the content is totally loaded.I want my preloader should show the progress.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your non-preloader assets are not exported nor placed on the first frame. Refer to [this](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/preloading/) article and browse to the 'loading complications' section